# bash + how to set cli PATH with version in sub folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel

Under `/usr/hdp` folder we can have only one the following sub-folders

```
2.6.5.0-292
2.6.4.0-91
2.6.0.3-8
```

example

```
ls /usr/hdp/
2.6.5.0-292  current  stack  file.txt
```

I want to use the following cli, and `$VERSION` could be one of the above versions

```
/usr/hdp/$VERSION/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh
```

then I did the following in my bash script

```
[[ -d /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292 ]] && VERSION=2.6.5.0-292 
[[ -d /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91  ]] && VERSION=2.6.4.0-91  
[[ -d /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8   ]] && VERSION=2.6.0.3-8
/usr/hdp/$VERSION/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh
```

Can we do the above setting in a more efficienct way without the test of `[[ -d  ...... ]]`?

Comment: As an aside, you should not be putting stuff in `/usr`; maybe in `/usr/local` but probably better to put it in `/opt` or `/srv` which are dedicated to third-party use.

Comment: this is part of HDP installation , ( hadoop cluster installation ) , so all sub folder under /usr is part of hdp installtion we not touch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to make this more efficient and if your requirement is that the directory should exist, there is no way to avoid checking for that. But you can at least avoid repeating yourself by using a loop.

```sh
for ver in 2.6.5.0-292 2.6.4.0-91 2.6.0.3-8; do
    if [[ -d "/usr/hdp/$ver" ]]; then
        VERSION=$ver
        break
    fi
done
```

The `break` causes the script to skip older versions as soon as it finds the newest in the list; your original code would weirdly do the opposite. If you genuinely want the oldest available version, reverse the ordering of the arguments to `for`.

Not checking for any others once you find a match is an actual optimization here, albeit a very minor one.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have *only one* of the folders  `2.6.5.0-292`, `2.6.4.0-91` or `2.6.0.3-8`, then the assignment `VERSION=2.6.*` will expand to the unique and correct folder.

So your script could look like:

```
VERSION=2.6.*
/usr/hdp/$VERSION/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh
```